# What is an instance of an NSObject

Tags: instance, nsobject, xcode3.2

I am a newbie, and I am wondering what an instance of NSObject is. I am working on Xcode 3.2 and want to know what the instance is. I've heard this term often and am confused by it.

Comment: an instance of "something" it's a modifier word that really needs some qualifications around it.  Put the word into context for us, though it sounds like you may be reading about an instance of a class?  Which would simply mean that, you have an instance of some class/object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Wikipedia on Objects in OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28computer_science%29)

> Objects in "object-oriented programming" basically are data structures
> combined with the associated processing routines. For instance, a file
> is an object: a collection of data and the associated read and write
> routines. Objects are considered instantiations of classes. In common
> parlance one refers to a file as a class, while the file is the
> object. A class defines properties an behaviour once, usually for
> multiple instantiations. In other disciplies, this distincion is also
> known as gen genus/species dichotomy.
>
> ...
>
> In a language where each object is created from a **class**, an object is
> called an **instance** of that class. If each object has a type, two
> objects with the same class would have the same data type. Creating an
> instance of a class is sometimes referred to as instantiating the
> class.

Essentially the [NSObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the base object type in Apple development.  The NSObject defines all things that are shared between all `classes` that extend from it:

> NSObject is the root class of most Objective-C class hierarchies.
> Through NSObject, objects inherit a basic interface to the runtime
> system and the ability to behave as Objective-C objects.

I would recommend taking some time to learn the basics of programming and OOP style programming if you are struggling with the definition of object instantiation.  Understanding this concept is paramount to success down the road, and if you continue without learning the basics you will create further frustration.